Why is the wiper fluid hose on the Mk7 Golf covered in cloth tape?
A friend had popped the hood of his Mk7 Golf the other day, and I noticed that the wiper fluid hose that runs the fluid from the reservoir to the hood-attached sprayer heads is covered in this fuzzy, cloth tape (see attached picture -- I couldn't get my phone to focus on the tube itself, but hopefully it gets the idea across).
Why use this kind of tape? My leading theory is that it provides some minimal thermal insulation, but given that:

Even commonly-available wiper fluid can be resistant to temperatures as cold as -40ºC (with slightly-less-common specialty fluids going as far as -49ºC)
Normal operating conditions involve either having the car stand still for hours at a time while parked and turned off, or driving for long enough that the engine bay gets pretty warm

It doesn't seem too likely that that's the case.


Cloth tape, perhaps as an added layer against uv radiation damaging plastic and rubber parts over time. Manufacturers have invested research along with trial and error over decades to use only components for reliability (long enough to last factory warranty) while minimizing costs.

Not sure about thermal insulation. Parked overnight it's not going to help much, but it will slow down thawing from the engine bay when running.

Along with what @FDryer has stated in comments, I'd suggest the primary reason for the cloth tape is abrasion resistance. Cloth tape is still very flexible, even when cold. It's just going to help the tube to last a lot longer.

In this case, it seems the hose is intended to settle down neatly into the space above the perforated metal. A more flexible hose could easily flop across the rubber seal as the hood is closed, cutting off the fluid flow unexpectedly.

I'd agree that it helps prevent abrasion to the water tube and helps prevent it kinking.
Edit: Just checked the wrapped part on my Golf 7.5 and there's definitely more than just a tube for the washers in there. It feels like wires for heated washer jets.
So the wrapping is to keep the pipe and other wires in a nice manageable bundle.

Yes, Golfs since Mk4 have heated windscreen washer tubes to both prevent them from damage and allowing them to work in cold.
